# keyevent in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

I've got an HTML element that I want to fill with specific content after someone presses "1" on the keyboard.
I use an external `.js` file which contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myid").html("Hello, 0111");
    $("#myid2").html("Lorem Ipsum");


    $(document).keyup(function (pressed_key) {
        if (pressed_key.key === "1") { 
            $("#myid").html("Button pressed");

            setTimeout(￼function () {
                $("#myid").html("Button not pressed");
            }, 1000);
        } 
    }

});
```

My HTML body looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="myid">0129</div>
    <div id="myid2"></div>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code is not working, it outputs the content of the HTML document.

However, if I comment out the `.keyup` function, the rest of the JavaScript code works and changes the HTML content accordingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: To check `space` chat, you can check the `pressed_key.which`, which is a integer and try the ascii code for space, for sample: `32`. Then try: `if (pressed_key.which === 32) { ... }`.

Comment: Step 1, always & next time without having to be asked, please & thank you: Check the browser console! `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, referring to the line `setTimeout(￼function () {` Copy&paste of your code into a hex editor reveals that you have the byte sequence `ef bf bc` in there between `…out` and `(￼fun…` - so re-type that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the argument passed to the `keyup` handler is the event, not the value of the character which was typed.

To fix this you can use `String.fromCharCode()`, along with the `which` property of the event, to get the character, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myid").html("Hello, 0111");
  $("#myid2").html("Lorem Ipsum");

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) === "1") {
      $("#myid").html("Button pressed");

      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myid").html("Button not pressed");
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid">0129</div>
<div id="myid2"></div>
```

Comment: this worked correctly. What is the advantage of using the Google source of jQuery? I just loaded it into the server so client get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass event to the keyup handler not the value of the character which was typed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myid").html("Hello, 0111");
  $("#myid2").html("Lorem Ipsum");

  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(event.which) === "1") {
      $("#myid").html("Button pressed");

      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myid").html("Button not pressed");
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid">0129</div>
<div id="myid2"></div>
```